# What is the "homepage" property in package.json?

Tags: node.js

I recently got into Web Development with NodeJS. I created a simple react app and wanted to deploy it on GitHub pages. I watched a couple of tutorials and in all of them they would add the "homepage" property in their package.json file.

```
{
 "name": "react-app",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "homepage": "https://github.com/owner/project#readme",
 "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
 },

 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
 },

 "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest"
    ]
 },

 "browserslist": {
    "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
    ]
 },

 "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
    ]
 }
}
```

So I wanted to know what is this "homepage" property?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, Create React App produces a build assuming your app is hosted at the server root.

To override this, specify the homepage in your package.json.

This will let Create React App correctly infer the root path to use in the generated HTML file.

for more info
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/